# Docker container exiting status

Tags: docker, containers

I have created one docker container using the following command:

```
# docker run -itd --name ssh -p "1111:22" <--Image Name-->
```

When I tried to list normally using command:

[image]

I tried also `restart` and `start` command but it's not working.

Comment: did you try removing ```d (detach mode)```  or check logs , you should see , what going on ?

Comment: Thanks Tarun...I will check it out

Comment: There's no need to use `-it` in `docker run`. Use `docker run -dp1111:22 --name ssh IMAGE`. Then run `docker ps -a`. Then run `docker logs ssh` to see the logs

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve], including enough source code from your Dockerfile and application to demonstrate the issue and the actual error message you're getting.  These details should be in text (not an image) and directly in the question (not behind a link).